# An equality of Lie algebras of contact type

Tags: lie-algebras, tensor-products

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a (finite dimensional) complex simple graded Lie algebra of contact type, that is
$$
\mathfrak g=\mathfrak g_{-2} \oplus \mathfrak g_{-1} \oplus \mathfrak g_0 \oplus \mathfrak g_1 \oplus \mathfrak g_2
$$
such that $\mathfrak g_{\pm 1} \ne 0$ and $\dim \mathfrak g_{\pm 2} =1$. We denote by $[\cdot, \cdot]$ the Lie bracket of $\mathfrak g$.

**Question:** Does it hold that
$$
[\mathfrak g_1, \mathfrak g_1] \otimes [\mathfrak g_{-1}, \mathfrak g_1]=[\mathfrak g_1 \otimes \mathfrak g_{-1}, \mathfrak g_1]? 
$$

Answer (score 1):

We probably need to make clear some definitions here. On the left hand side you have a tensor product of bits of $\mathfrak{g}$ and on the right you have a bracket involving such a tensor product but also an honest piece of $\mathfrak{g}$.

The natural understanding of that right hand side (to me) is via the induced Lie algebra representation on a tensor product:

$$[a\otimes b,c] := [a,c]\otimes b + a\otimes[b,c]$$

So using this we would get:

$$ [\mathfrak{g}_1 \otimes \mathfrak{g}_{-1},\mathfrak{g}_1] \subseteq \left([\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_1]\otimes \mathfrak{g}_{-1}\right) + \left(\mathfrak{g}_1\otimes[\mathfrak{g}_{-1},\mathfrak{g}_1]\right) \subseteq \left(\mathfrak{g}_2\otimes \mathfrak{g}_{-1}\right) + \left(\mathfrak{g}_1\otimes\mathfrak{g}_{0}\right) $$

(Note that I didn't put $\oplus$ because for different graded pieces we might get non-direct sums but in this case you can see they are in fact direct.)
This is not going to be the same as the left hand side which is contained in:
$$ \mathfrak{g}_2\otimes \mathfrak{g}_{0}$$

Edit: As per the comments, all the inequalities mentioned are in fact equalities in the case of a grading of height 2 (more generally than contact structures).

Comment: Thanks! Any reference for this induced Lie algebra representation on a tensor product?

Comment: Second, under which hypothesys do we have that the first $\subseteq$ is a $=$?

Comment: @Bobech For a reference you can check out pretty much any text on Lie algebra representations (e.g. Fulton and Harris's Representation theory). As to making the first $\subseteq$ an equality it should always be one I think. As long as we have for every element of $\mathfrak{g}_1$ a non-zero element of $\mathfrak{g}_{-1}$ that commutes with it and vice versa (so we can make one of the terms vanish and still cover the whole of the other term) and I think this isn't too hard to show. I was just being cautious making it an inequality since that was all I needed.

Comment: I think the second $\subseteq$ is a strict inequality though as $[\mathfrak{g}_{1},\mathfrak{g}_{-1}]$ is never equal to $\mathfrak{g}_{0}$. I think we must have $[\mathfrak{g}_{1},\mathfrak{g}_{1}] = \mathfrak{g}_{2}$ though and in more generality than just contact structures.

Comment: the second $\subseteq$ is an equality for a graded Lie algebra of contact type, by a result of Tanaka in "On non-degenerate real hypersurfaces, graded Lie algebras and Cartan connections"

Comment: Good note! Yes so that seems to make the whole thing an equality

Comment: In that case it would hold that
$$
(\mathfrak g_2 \otimes \mathfrak g_0)+(\mathfrak g_1 \otimes \mathfrak g_1)=[\operatorname{Hom}(\mathfrak g_1,\mathfrak g_1),\mathfrak g_1].
$$
How can such a space be described?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135042/discussion-between-callum-and-bobech).